# Solution of $z(t+a) = h(a)z(t)$

Tags: functional-equations

I'm reading Howard Georgi online book on [The Physics of Waves](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~hgeorgi/new.htm) and found the following argument. Given the functional equation

$$ z(t+a) = h(a)z(t) $$

he makes the following derivation (I'm citing the book):

> If we differentiate both sides of [the aforementioned equation] with respect to $a$, we obtain
>   $$ z'(t+a) = h'(a)z(t). $$
>   Setting $a = 0$ gives
>   $$ z'(t) = Hz(t) $$
>   where
>   $$ H \equiv h'(0). $$
>   This implies
>   $$ z(t) \propto e^{Ht}. $$
>   Thus the irreducible solution is an exponential! [...]

How can he differentiate with respect to $a$ then solve the resulting differential equation with respect to $t$? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: Do you know if there is a solutions manual to this book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to realize that
$$\frac{d z(t+a)}{d a}=\frac{d z(t+a)}{dt}$$
since changing $a$ and changing $t$ produce the same change in the argument of $z$.

Comment: Indeed, silly me. Thank you!